# How do I avoid recursive task list traversal for a task-based program?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have a class ITask with a virtual method:

```
class ITask
{
  public:
      virtual void Execute() = 0;
};
```

And I made a system that distributes tasks on different threads, making them execute in parallel.The thing is, I need some tasks to not be able to execute before certain other tasks have been completed.A single task can depend on multiple parent tasks, so I can't do something along the lines of this:

```
void Task::Execute()
{
//do stuff
//finished

    for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
    {
     ThreadingSystem::QueuedTasks.push_back(children[i]);
    }
}
```

So instead I did something like this:

```
class Task : public ITask
{
    public:
     void Execute();

     unsigned int dependency;

     vector<Task*> children;
};
```

void Task::Execute()
{
    //do stuff
    //finished

```
for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
{
    children[i]->dependency--;
}
```

}

so basically this way only the Tasks that have a dependency of 0U will be free to be executed, so a Task would need to wait all its parents to finish before it can execute.Now the problem is, this system gets very  messy, for instance:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
    {
        if(children[i]->dependency == 0U)
        {
           ThreadingSystem::QueuedTasks.push_back(children[i]);
           //either remove added task from children or set a flag in it to mark as "queued"
        }
    }
```

And I have to basically call this non-stop until all children are out of the vector.The first iteration might only send 2 Tasks to the multithreaded queue, the second iteration might send another 3, the third iteration another 7, etc.It's utterly unpredictable and has a lot of branching and looping involved.Maybe the entire idea about the dependency integers is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use getters/setters rather than direct access to `dependencies`.

  - Something like `child->AddDependency` and `child->SatisfyDependency`.
- `child->SatisfyDependency` should add the child to the queue when the dependency count hits zero.
- Now, instead of polling, adding the child to the queue is triggered directly by the "no more dependencies" event.

You should consider pulling in an already-debugged task-based thread pool library if you can find one, though.

Comment: Yeah I know I can use TBB under the free license version, but I'm actually doing it for skill development/educational purpose

Answer (score 1):

### Data Structure

You can build a dependency tree based on your original task that you want to execute. Let's assume that you want to execute TaskA, which depends on TaskB and TaskC. TaskC itself depends on TaskD.

Let your Tasks save their children, which are their dependencies!

```
class Task : public ITask
{
    public:
     void Execute();

     vector<Task*> children;
};
```

For TaskA, the vector *children* would consist of TaskB and TaskC. TaskB has no further child tasks. TaskC has the child TaskD.

### Execution

The threads in your ThreadingSystem will parse the Task tree (starting at TaskA) and search for a leaf, i.e. a Task that has no children. If a thread finds a leaf, it will make sure that no other threads can run that Task simultaneously. A flag might work.

After execution, the leaf will be removed from the tree and another leaf is searched.

If there is no leaf available currently, the thread has to wait until one becomes available. You could wake them up whenever a leaf has been executed.

The ThreadingSystem is done with execution when there is no Task left, i.e. when TaskA is removed from the tree. You could send an event or unblock the caller or something then.

### Note

As you commented an answer, you do this for educational purpose. Try to implement a tree, and if you are done, you can could try to implement a (directed) graph. Or implement cycle-detection. Try to speed up the performance of finding/caching leaves etc. etc.

Or ... use an existing framework. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, seems like this way is definitely faster, however I think it'll still require a separate traversal for each "dependency layer"?Btw to get tasks to the threads, the thread just pops a concurrent queue that uses interlockedincrement.It works really fast, however I guess I'll need some extra step to move the tasks from the dependency graph to the concurrent queue.

Comment: @DEIMOS You can speed up the "tree traversal" if you push all the leaves into your queue during startup. Save the parent of a leaf in your data structure. If the execution is finished, you can look up the parent and remove the child. If no more childs are left, add it to the queue and pop the next. If you reach the task with no parent left, you completed your tree.